# Pillow: undefined symbol: PyCapsule_New

Tags: python, django, apache, centos

I have this prerequisites:

- CentOS 6.5
- Python2.7  installed with commands `./configure
  --prefix=/usr/local --enable-unicode=ucs4; make; make altinstall;`
- httpd as web-server for Django web-site

I get such traceback:

```
...
File "/var/www/html/mysite.com/mylib/uploader/fields.py", line 8, in <module>
 from PIL import Image
File "/var/www/html/mysite.com/eggs/Pillow-2.4.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/PIL/Image.py", line 53, in <module>
File "/var/www/html/mysite.com/eggs/Pillow-2.4.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/PIL/_imaging.py", line 7, in <module>
File "/var/www/html/mysite.com/eggs/Pillow-2.4.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/PIL/_imaging.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: /tmp/python-eggs/Pillow-2.4.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg-tmp/PIL/_imaging.so: undefined symbol: PyCapsule_New
```

When I try to execute `from PIL import Image` from Django shell - it passes without errors.

Googling for this error does not helped me much, kindly help.

UPDATE:
Ive tried to serve the web-site with Djangos internal server (`manage.py runserver` command), and it worked OK.

Comment: Try enabling debug in your settings.py and carefully inspecting the full handler500 output. Pay special attention to the python environment. I suspect django is not picking up your altinstall'ed version of python, but instead running an older python part of CentOS that does not yet support python Capsules.

Comment: @user590028 For some reason, even with `DEBUG=True` I get standard apache 500 page.

Comment: Try purging the contents of your apache egg cache

Comment: @user590028 I've tried it, and deleting `*.pyc` too. By hacky way - placing `raise Exception(sys.version)` in `settings.py` Ive got version with which httpd launches Django - 2.6.6. Very strange!

Comment: Check your wsgi.py startup script. The top line (she-bang) -- make sure it's linked to the correct python

Comment: I am having same issue with CentOS 6.6 (Final) and Python2.7(by defalut there is a Python2.6).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar bug.

What was happening was my python2.7 install was picking up packages from the system python2.6 (through some PYTHONPATH muckery)

To debug, drop a breakpoint right before the thing that gets imported and:

```
import sys
for path in sys.path:
    print(path)
```

Ideally it should only contain python2.7 things, but you've probably leaked a python2.6 thing onto it (or the other way around)